# Templated assignment operator and self-check

Tags: c++, templates, variable-assignment

I'm reading a book on template programming, and one of the examples they have code that does a self check in a templated assignment operator. Basically it's something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:

    template <typename O>
    Foo<T> operator= (const Foo<O> & other)
    {
        if ((void *)this == (void *)&other)
        {
            std::cerr << "success" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "failure" << std::endl;
        }
        return *this
    }
};
```

Now, from my understanding, since the templated assignment operator doesn't prevent the default assignment operator from being generated, for cases where O = T, the default assignment operator will always be selected over the templated version. That is, in this situation it will never be the case that O = T.

What I'm wondering is whether my understanding of this is correct. If it is, is there some sort of a tricky hierarchy (like if I derive Foo from something else or if it is derived from something else) where the assignment operator will print out "success"?

I've tried several things but I can't really get it to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are missing the return on operator=. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: why did you not try this before posting the question?

Comment: Well, you can force it: http://ideone.com/W3zgy

Comment: Note that the test for self-reference in the templated `operator=` is broken. It will work only if the `Foo<O>` and the `Foo<T>` are located in exactly the same memory location, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: sorry, i edited the question.. yeah i typed it out here, but I do have one with a return code in my terminal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're right, or both MSVC 11 and g++ 4.7.1 got it wrong.

I.e., normally that templated assignment operator will not be called: the automatically generated copy assignment operator will be called.

To output "success", do like this, and hope that compiler uses Empty Base class Optimization (EBO):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo;

template<> class Foo<void> {};

template <typename T>
class Foo: public Foo< void >
{
public:

    template <typename O>
    void operator=( const Foo<O> & other )
    {
        if ((void *)this == (void *)&other)
        {
            std::cerr << "success" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "failure" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> a, b;

    Foo<void>& v = a;
    a = v;
}
```